# A or no article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why does the article apply here, although the word poses is plural?

> I have my digital camera, I force your mother to make ***a*** million poses.

The phrase from the song:) (Motherlover)

Comment: You could say "one million poses", but you need something before 'million'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article applies to the quantity, **million**. You need an article or number in front of things like *hundred*, *thousand*, *million* for them to be correct.